# Comparison of two common comparison algorithms and their Big O help please

Tags: c++, c, big-o

Today my professor gave us 2 take home questions as practice for upcoming array unit in C and I am wondering what exactly the sorting algorithm these 2 problems resemble and what their Big O is. **Now**, I am not coming here just expecting answers and I have **ALREADY** solved them, but I am not **confident** in my answers so I will post them udner each question and if I am wrong, please correct me and explain my error in thinking.

***Question 1:***

If we decide to go through an array's(**box**) element(**folders**) one at a time. Starting at the first element and comparing it with the next. Then if they are the same the comparison ends, however if both are not equal then it moves on to comparing the next two ELEMENTS [2] and [3]. This process is repeated and will stop once last two elements are compared and note that the array IS already sorted by last name and we are looking for same first name! Example: [ Harper Steven, Hawking John, Ingleton Steven]

**My believed answer:**

I beleive it is O(n) because it's just going over the elements of an array comparing array[0] to array[1] and then array[2] to array[3] ect ect. This process is linear and continues until the last two are compared. Definitely not logn because we aren't multiplying or diving by 2.

***Final Question:***
Suppose we have a box of folders each containing info on one person. If we were to want to look for people with same first name, we could first start by placing a sticker on the first folder in the box and then going through the folders after it in an orderly fashion until we find person with same name. If we find a folder with same name, we move that folder next to the folder with a sticker. Once we find ONE case where two people have same name, we stop and go to sleep because we're lazy. If the first search fails however, we simply remove sticker and place it on next folder and then continue as we did earlier. We repeat this process until sticker is on last folder in a scenario where we have no two people with same name.

This array is NOT sorted and compares the first folder with sticker folder[0] with the next i folder[i] elements.

**My answer:**

I feel like this can't be O(n), but maybe O(n^2) where it kinda feels like we have an array and then we keep repeating the process where n is proportional to the square of the input(folders). I could be wrong here through >.>

Comment: I am truely, sorry, I meant to say element!

Comment: I have fixed it and there should be no more errors in the question.

Comment: In the first question, you say "note that the array IS already sorted". Is this also true in the second question? Is it sorted by first name, or by last? (That could change what "… in an orderly fashion …" means.) Beyond that, you're right that we have to do N searches (however long a search takes) followed by 1 swap (which seems ambiguous, and could mean a linear shift, but it can still be ignored). So, if it's a linear search, that's N searches that each take O(N) time, so yes, O(N^2). But if it's a bisect search, then that's N searches that each take O(log N) time, so O(N log N).

Comment: OKay, I edited one last time >.<, the first one is indeed sorted by last name and we are looking for first name. Second is unsorted and we are looking for same first name, but this time the process doens't end at the end of element if no same name is found. because it just repeats and compares with second folder now.

Comment: Q1:  What's the _question_?  You describe searching for two consecutive elements that are the same, but then what's the deal with names you mention?  Can you state the actual problem clearly to someone who has not read the assignment?

Comment: big O means worst-case. Imagine the worst-case in your final question. the two people at the end of your array have the same first name only or none of the names match.. which means you need to do n + n-1 + n-2 + n-3 till 2 look ups.. bound by (n)*(n-1) lookups i.e. O(N^2).

Comment: Well, I reworded it but it's in essence what it infers, and the names are kinda an analogy, think of it as an sorted array from least to greated value length and we are searching for same word.

Comment: I still don't follow Q1.  Searching for first name (only?), searching for two consecutive elements that are equal?  You descriptions don't agree and you are not being rigorous enough or stating everything needed.  Think about writing a program:  How can it possibly work if you don't put in everything?  Try explaining the algoritm in pseudocode at the very least, or runnable code is even better.

Comment: It was originally a full blown 2 paragraph question and i cut it down because a lot of unnecessary info where it was describing the worker Bob (useless info) who was going to do this comparing.

Comment: @user3718584, I'd like to point out that the Data Structures and Algorithms class I took in high school (A.P.) was the single most useful thing I learned about programming in a classroom situation.  I also applied this kind of knowledge in "real world", sorting boxes of check stubs for example, ridiculously faster than anyone had ever done it before at the office.

Comment: Hmm, @user3718584, you compare elements 0 and 1, if they are not equal you compare elements 2 and 3, etc. this will find two identical elements that are aligned suitably, and not spot them if they are aligned differently (e.g. [A, B, B, C] A!=B, B!=C]).  Are you "looking for two equal elements in a sorted array"?  Is that the problem that you can't seem to state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right on both questions… but it would help to explain things a bit more rigorously. I don't know what the standards of your class are; you probably don't need an actual proof, but showing more detailed reasoning than "we aren't multiplying or dividing by two" never hurts. So…

---

In the first question, there's clearly nothing happening here but comparisons, so that's what we have to count.

And the worst case is obviously that you have to go through the whole array.

So, in that case, you have to compare `a[0] == a[1]`, then `a[1] == a[2]`, …, `a[N-1] == a[N]`. For each of `N-1` elements, there's 1 comparison. That's `N-1` steps, which is obviously `O(N)`.

The fact that the array is sorted turns out to be irrelevant here. (Of course since they're not sorted by your search key—that is, they're sorted by last name, but you're comparing by first name—that was already pretty obvious.)

---

In the second question, there are two things happening here: comparisons, and then moves.

For the comparisons, the worst case is that you have to do all `N` searches because there are no matches. As you say, we start with `a[0]` vs. `a[1]`, …, `a[N]`; then `a[1]` vs. `a[2]`, …, `a[N]`, etc. So, `N-1` comparisons, then `N-2`, and so on down to `0`. So the total number of comparisons is `sum(0…N-1)`, which is `N*(N-1)/2`, or `N^2/2 - N/2`, which is `O(N^2)`.

For the moves, the worst case is that you find a match between `a[0]` and `a[N]`. In that case, you have to swap `a[N]` with `a[N-1]`, then `a[N-1]` with `a[N-2]`, and so on until you've swapped `a[2]` with `a[1]`. So, that's `N-1` swaps, which is `O(N)`, which you can ignore because you've already got an `O(N^2)` term.

---

As a side note, I'm not sure from your description whether you're talking about an array from `a[0…N]`, or an array of length N, so `a[0…N-1]`, so there could be an off-by-one error in both of the above. But it should be pretty easy to prove to yourself that it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I don't see any moving in Q2.  The sticker is just a pointer to keep track of the current candidate element.  It's a search, not a re-ordering.

Comment: Thank you! It really helps to get a second view of how my answer is right.

Comment: @jdlugosz: "If we find a folder with same name, we move that folder next to the folder with a sticker". How is that not a move?

Comment: @user3718584: It's important to be able to write things out in a way that actually counts the (worst-case) steps, instead of just noticing that it looks linear. In many cases things are obvious, but there are cases where it, e.g., looks like you're dividing by 2, but you're actually doing 2x as much work each time so it's still linear.

Comment: @abarnert that "move" is a one time thing.  Move one folder next to the other, then done.  I took that as a description of "return" rather than an insertion that itself needs time to perform.  A physical box of paper can be inserted in one step, not needing to move each folder individually.

Comment: @jdlugosz: How do you move `a[6]` next to `a[2]` without moving `a[3]` out of the way first? And how do you move `a[3]` out of the way without moving `a[4]` out of the way first? (Of course in practice you're going to do one big `memmove` and then one assignment, but that `memmove` is just as `O(N)` as a bunch of separate swaps.)

Comment: @abarnert in the physical example the insertion is a box of file folders, not (say) individually slotted CD box cabinet.  In the program, it does not have to be a linear array!  It might be a linked list, so inserting the pointer into the found spot is O(1).  It might be an array for each "drawer" so inserting work is limited to the drawer capacity not the entire n.  In real programming, if inserting had a large enough coefficient to matter, I'd use a non-linear data structure like a tree.

Comment: @jdlugosz: The asker uses the word "array" 10 times. He talks about indexing the array, which you can't do with a linked list (unless you want it to take linear time). He talks about it being sorted, with the implication that this could allow bisecting, which wouldn't be true with a linked list. It's pretty clear that both the asker and his professor really mean array here, and if you changed the data structure so you could change the algorithm instead of evaluating the algorithm as given, you might be able to argue your way to a good grade, but it wouldn't be what he was looking for…

Answer (score 1):

Scenario 2, a method of finding two matching items of arbitrary value, is indeed “quadratic”.  Each pass looking for a match of one candidate against all the rest of the elements is O(n).  But you repeat *that* n times.  The value of n drops as you go so a detailed number of comparisons would be closer to n+(n-1)+(n-2)+ … 1 which is (n+1)×(n/2) or ½(n²+n) but all we care about is the overall shape of the curve so don't worry about the lower order terms or the coefficients.  It's O(n²).